# xUnit testing error (CS5001) Program does not contain a static Main method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Good day/evening!
I am trying to do a test program in xUnit with the following code in Visual Studio Code:

```
using Xunit;
using FluentAssertions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Ferma;

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public static void EmployeeTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        List<FermaMea.Employee> List = new List<FermaMea.Employee>();
        //Act + Assert
        List.Should().Contain(p => p.GID == "Z0001");
    }
}
```

The file I am trying to test this code with is:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Serilog;

namespace Ferma
{
    public partial class FermaMea
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<Employee> myEmployee = new List<Employee>();
            myEmployee.Add(new Employee() { GID = "Z0001", FirstName = "Billy Bob", LastName = "Bean", Department = "Cows11" });
            myEmployee.Add(new Employee() { GID = "Z0002", FirstName = "Joey", LastName = "Ray", Department = "Field" });

            string ExportToJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEmployee, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(@"..\Emp.App\config\Employee.json", ExportToJson);
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public string? GID { get; set; }
            public string? FirstName { get; set; }
            public string? LastName { get; set; }
            public string? Department { get; set; }

            public Employee()
            {
                Log.Information("New employee has been added");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program folder structure is as following:

```
MainFolder
    -> Emp.Test-> UnitTest1.cs
    -> Emp.Lib -> Employee.cs
    -> Emp.App -> Main.cs (Here is my main program, which, by my understanding, is not affected in this question. 
                  But if I'm mistaken, please tell me and I will provide all relevant informations.
```

Emp.Test.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0-preview-20211130-02"/>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.7"/>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.7"/>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2-pre.12"/>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.2.0"/>
    
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Emp.App\Emp.App.csproj"/>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Emp.Lib\Emp.Lib.csproj"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Emp.Lib.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.1-dev-00947"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0-preview-20211130-02"/>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2-pre.12"/>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.2.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The error I'm getting is this one:

```
----- Running test method "Ferma.UnitTest1.EmployeeTest" -----

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Emp.Lib -> C:\WORK\demofarm\Emp.Lib\bin\Debug\net6.0\Emp.Lib.dll
  Emp.App -> c:\WORK\demofarm\Emp.App\bin\Debug\net6.0\Emp.App.dll
CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [c:\WORK\demofarm\Emp.Test\Emp.Test.csproj]

Build FAILED.

CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [c:\WORK\demofarm\Emp.Test\Emp.Test.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.90
```

If I forgot anything, please let me know and I will provide anything relevant.

Thank you so much, in advance,
Ionut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have installed `xUnit` to your project, the compiler will **Generate Program File** with a `Main` method automatically configured to run the given tests.
This configuration in `.csproj` file will prevent that.

```xml
<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
```

Then you have to create the `Main` method by yourself.

---

You have this configuration in `Emp.Lib` and `Emp.Test` projects.
In `Emp.Lib` you have a `Main` method but not in `Emp.Test`.

## You need to do

Generate your `Main` method in `Emp.Test` or remove `GenerateProgramFile` tag in `Emp.Test.csproj` file.

**Emp.Test.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile> <!-- remove this -->
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile> <!-- remove this -->
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Deleting the files did the trick.